# Div selector is not sending the debugger in function definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $('#clickme').click(function () {
            alert('Entered'); $('#book').animate({
                opacity: 0.25, left: '+=50', height: 'toggle'
            }, 5000, function () {
                // Animation    complete. 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="clickme" class="hiii">
        Click here
    </div>
    <img id="book" src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="" width="10" height="12" style="position: relative;
        left: 10px;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a reproducible test case on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you saying the function runs but doesn't trigger debugging, or that it doesn't run at all? Some browsers may ignore the statement if the debugging tools aren't already open. (Also, what does this have to do with asp.net?)

Comment: either case is not happening.

Comment: Show us a JSFiddle then.

Comment: Does the function work if you remove the `debugger` statement?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pankajgarg10/HWGjd/

Comment: Fixed your [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/HWGjd/15/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need to wrap your function in the `$(document).ready` function to ensure the DOM is available i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.hiii').click(function () { 
     //.. your code
   });

});
```

That would account for this missing handler. I think it's the same issue as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939911/whats-wrong-with-this-blur-function/8940017#8940017).

Answer (score 1):

My guess it that that `div` wasn't rendered when you attched him the click event.
you should use JQuery `on`\ `live`\ `delegate` function, based on your JQuery version:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` version(You referenced JQuery1.7.1):

```
$("body").on("click", ".hiii", function(){
    debugger;
    $('#book').animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: '+=50',
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 5000, function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });       
);
```

By the way your `<div>` has an id and a class, selecting by id is way more efficient. You probably want to change the selector from `.hiii` to `#clickme`

---

Updated by your's comments:
You faced problems because you tried to attach an event listener to elements that wasn't rendered yet. Fixed version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function doAnimation (){
        $('#clickme').click(function () {
            alert('Entered'); $('#book').animate({
                opacity: 0.25, left: '+=50', height: 'toggle'
            }, 5000, function () {
                // Animation    complete. 
            });
        });
};
$(doAnimation);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="clickme" class="hiii">
        Click here
    </div>
    <img id="book" src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="" width="10" height="12" style="position: relative;
        left: 10px;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery DOM ready [article](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @StackOverflowUser. Your edit didn't add any info. Give us a JSFiddle please, so we can stop guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the updates working fine there and  
I have update the question now with complete page. This includes JS and HTML both. Issue is still there while implementing it in page.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser. Found the problem. Updated my answer.

Comment: What if we enclose the click function in "$(document).ready(function(){
"   ? as told in below mentioned answers.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser. It's exactly the same thing, `$(document).ready(foo)` == `$(foo)`. The second version is shorter... Choose what you like more. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the project will solve the issue